# SSIS 2012 development error while selecting oledb destination table in dataflow task

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, oledbdestination

I am in  dataflow destination (OLE DB Destination) screen. I am able to connect to the database and I see the destination tables in the dropdown.

When I click the 'Mappings' option the left, or if I click on 'View existing data' button, I get an error :

> Validation error. Data Flow Task: Data Flow Task: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Unspecified error".  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Communication link failure".
>
> Validation error. Data Flow Task OLE DB Destination [31]: Failed to open a fastload rowset for "[dbo].[xxxxxxxx]". Check that the object exists in the database.   xxxxxxxxxxx.dtsx    0   0

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you provide a screen shot of the oledb connection manager used?

Comment: done. Thanks Hadi

Comment: While searching i found the following MSDN topic. They suggested changing the provider to OLEDB provider for SQL Server https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fab0e3bf-4adf-4f17-b9f6-7b7f9db6523c/communication-link-failure-when-connecting-to-remote-database Try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved after I closed and reopened Visual Studio. Hadi's solution looks like a good permanent fix.